# Script to Update label and its link address of OOTB Button webpart- SharePoint Online Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

Script or way to quickly Update label and its link address of OOTB Button webpart- SharePoint Online Page? Without having to do manually.

Scenario is  Need to update on more than 100 teamsites which has the Out of the box button webpart with same label and link.

Any help is much appreciated....! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $row.URL -Credential $O365Credential

#To Get the control*********
Page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "home.aspx"
foreach($webpart in $Page.Controls){
   
 if($webpart.Title -eq "Button" -and ($webpart.HtmlPropertiesData.Contains("Log a ticket") -or $webpart.HtmlPropertiesData.Contains("Log a ticket with IT"))) 
            {
                $selectedControlIndex = $index
            }
            $index = $index + 1
        }

        $Page.Controls.RemoveAt($selectedControlIndex)
        $Page.Save("home.aspx")
        $Page.Publish()

#To add new button control and set the properties***********

$jsonProps =  @'
        {
            "controlType":3,
            "position":{"zoneIndex":1,"sectionIndex":1,"controlIndex":1,"layoutIndex":1},
            "webPartId":"0f087d7f-520e-42b7-89c0-496aaf979d58",
            "webPartData":{
                "id":"0f087d7f-520e-42b7-89c0-496aaf979d58",
                "instanceId":"77116d7a-3558-4da8-a194-86f2ea286fb8",
                "title":"Button",
                "description":"Add a clickable button with a custom label and link.",
                "serverProcessedContent":{"htmlStrings":{},"searchablePlainTexts":{"label":"Log with IT Team"},"imageSources":{},"links":{"linkUrl":"https://www.Google.com"}},
                "dataVersion":"1.0",
                "properties":{"alignment":"Center"}
            },
            "emphasis":{},
            "reservedHeight":40,
            "reservedWidth":744,
            "addedFromPersistedData":true
        }
'@

 Add-PnPPageWebPart  -Page $Page -DefaultWebPartType "Button" -Section 1 -Column 2 -Order 1 -WebPartProperties $jsonProps
         $Page.Save("home.aspx")
         $Page.Publish()
```

Please Note:

1. I have hard coded Section and Column but you extract.
2. Also some of the looping and If conditions can be simplified as required

Answer (score 0):

Do all the web parts have some thing in common? We can get the web part through PowerShell, still we need to identify the correct one to update.

As you have over 100 team sites, do the URL of pages using the web part recorded? We need either page URL or GUID to get the web part with `Get-PnPWebPart`

[Get-PnPWebPart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpwebpart?view=sharepoint-ps)

Set a web part property with [Set-PnPWebPartProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpwebpartproperty?view=sharepoint-ps)

An example you can refer to is like [this](https://www.midishares.nl/sharepoint/bulk-update-pages-with-webparts-using-powershell/) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/addupdate-delete-webpart-of-a-sharepoint-page-using-pnp-powershell) .

**Update:**
For modern web parts, the above things will not work. I tested with some examples, we can get the web part through following cmdlets. The web parts are considered as client Side Components. And the properties you want to update, the label and link are enclosed in the HtmlPropertiesData, which is read-only. I am not sure if there are other approaches to update the settings of a modern web part. You can try to open a service request about it.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $credentials
$button=Get-PnPClientSideComponent -Page Home |Where-Object{$_.Title -eq "Button"}
$button.HtmlPropertiesData
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but no web parts returned. 
 $webparts = Get-PnPWebPart -ServerRelativePageUrl "/SitePages/home.aspx" -Identity 3f05c7c2-930f-4f14-bb79-d548ef80126b
 foreach($webpart in $webparts){

    if($webpart.WebPart.Title -eq "MyWebPart") {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $webpart
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "No webpart found..."
    }
 }

Comment: $Page = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "home.aspx"
foreach($webpart in $Page.Controls){}   ---- This works but not sure how to update the properties.

Comment: Hi, @Vish, I updated with some new findings.

Comment: That's Correct. I tried the same but unable to update the value. I am thinking of use Client object model and try to update. Another way could be to remove the control and add new Webpart to the page. Thank you Jerry.

Comment: Hi Jerry, Get the index of the button control and delete it from Page. After that Add the button control again with all the details

Comment: Hi, @Vish, yes that will be the ultimate solution for you task. It is easier to just remove and add again which I just missed. Glad to hear you get the right way for it.